# How to define an index to use in a Mango Query

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-nano, couchdb-mango

I am trying to create a CouchDB Mango Query with an index with the hope that the query runs faster. At the moment I have the following Mango Query which returns what I am looking for but it's slow. Therefore, I assume, I need to create an index to make it faster. I need help figuring out how to create that index.

```
    selector: {
      categoryIds: {
        $in: categoryIds,
      },
    },
    sort: [{ publicationDate: 'desc' }],
```

You can assume that my documents are let say news articles from different categories. Therefore in each document I have a field that contains one or more categories that the news article belongs to. For that I have an array of `categoryIds` for each document. My query needs to be optimized for queries like "Give me all news that have categoryId1 in their array of categoryIds sorted by publicationDate". What I don't know how to do is 1. How to define an index 2. What that index should be 3. How to use that index in "use_index" field of the Mango Query. Any help is appreciated.

Update after "Alexis Côté" answer:

If I define the index like this:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/0f11ca4ef1ea06de05b31e6bd8265916c1bbe821",
  "_rev": "6-adce50034e870aa02dc7e1e075c78361",
  "language": "query",
  "views": {
    "categoryIds-json-index": {
      "map": {
        "fields": {
          "categoryIds": "asc"
        },
        "partial_filter_selector": {}
      },
      "reduce": "_count",
      "options": {
        "def": {
          "fields": [
            "categoryIds"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And run the Mango Query like this:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "categoryIds": {
         "$in": [
            "e0bd5f97ac35bdf6893351337d269230"
         ]
      }
   },
   "use_index": "categoryIds-json-index"
}
```

It still does return the results but they are not sorted in the order I want by publicationDate. So I am not clear what you are suggesting the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create an index as documented [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#post--db-_index)
2. In your case, you will need an index on the "categoryIds" field.
3. You can specify the index using `"use_index": "_design/<name>"`

   > Note:The query planner should automatically pick this index if it's compatible.

Comment: @Dogahe To use the sort, I think the field must be in the query and maybe in the index. Not sure if you can actually sort an index with the $in operator